# dependent picklist value in defaultValues force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is there any limitation that dependent picklist value is not being populated using defaultValues in force:createRecord?

```
 createINTRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        var iws = component.get("v.parentIWS");
        console.log('IWS details Specialty__c: '+ iws.Specialty__c);
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord"); 
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": 'Apprenticeship__c',
            "recordTypeId": null,
            'defaultFieldValues': { 
                'Opportunity__c': iws.Opportunity__c,  
                'InternshipWorkSite__c': iws.Id,              
                'Track__c': iws.TrackFamily__c, // Controlling Field
                'Job_Category__c': iws.Specialty__c, // Dependent Field
                'Employer__c' : iws.Account__c,
                'Cohort_Sem__c' :  iws.Opportunity__r.Cohort_Sem__c,
                'Start_Date__c' : iws.InternshipStartDate__c,
                'Site_Location__c' : iws.Site_Located__c,
                'Internship_Cluster__c': '--None--'
            }               
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();

    }
```

Issue:

```
'Track__c'-----> // Controlling Field
    'Job_Category__c'---> // Dependent Field of Track__c
        'Internship_Cluster__c'---> //Dependent Field of Job_Category__c
```

I am able to assign the value to only top level picklist, but not dependent fields. I can see the value printing in the console and also value available in the picklist. However the value is not populated in the form.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ajay, I am looking to implement similar functionality. Is this issue still existing or is there any work around for this. Thanks.

Comment: Issue is still exists. Work around for now is update the record after insert with wf rule